# Class not changing state of pyserial connection when unplug device

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am trying to do simple serial link program for school project and I have small problem. I created class to maintain serial communication, but when I unplug and plug back serial port, it doesnt change state of serial connection (`self.ser` have still same object like when it was initalized). I want it to recconnect and continue to work. Can you please help me and tell mi what I am doing wrong? I am new to python. Thank you very much!

```
import serial
import uuid


class SerialWrapper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)

    def handleconnect(self):
        try:
            if self.ser is None:
                self.ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
                self.ser.close()
                self.ser.open()
                print("Reconnecting...")

        except:
            if not (self.ser is None):
                self.ser.close()
                self.ser = None
                print("Disconnecting")
            else:
                print("No Connection")

    def serialwrite(self, data):
        self.handleconnect()

        try:
            datalength = self.ser.write(data.encode())
            print("Writing data...")
            return datalength

        except:
            print("Error in writing data")

    def serialread(self, datalength):
        self.handleconnect()

        try:
            data = self.ser.read(datalength).decode()
            print("Reading data...")
            return data

        except:
            print("Error in reading data")


def main():
    ser = SerialWrapper()
    while 1:
        value = uuid.uuid4().hex
        length = ser.serialwrite(value)
        print(ser.serialread(length))


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that on every end of cycle must be port closed with `self.ser.close()` and then at the start of new cycle openened again with `self.ser.open()`